# How to get PodSandboxConfig object in PullImageRequest on container runtime interface interface

Tags: kubernetes, interface, containers, runtime, container-runtime-interface

I'm working on a new CRI for Kubernetes and I would like to have information about the pod configuration in the PullImage method, but `PullImageRequest` always contains the sandbox configuration with nil value.

As you can see, PullImageRequest contains a PodSanboxConfig object:

```
type PullImageRequest struct {
    // Spec of the image.
    Image *ImageSpec `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=image" json:"image,omitempty"`
    // Authentication configuration for pulling the image.
    Auth *AuthConfig `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=auth" json:"auth,omitempty"`
    // Config of the PodSandbox, which is used to pull image in PodSandbox context.
    SandboxConfig *PodSandboxConfig `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=sandbox_config,json=sandboxConfig" json:"sandbox_config,omitempty"`
}
```

I'm working with

> Kubernetes 1.11.3

and

> cri/runtime/v1alpha2

How can I do to get the PodSandboxConfig object?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to the value to be nil? or not nil?  What information do you want to pass through CRI?

Comment: I want it to be NOT nil, so I can get information that I pass through the sandbox configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71745) about it on Kubernetes github and they are working on it in this [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/71764).